# How to create login with react native and how to validate session

Tags: react-native

I need to create a login feature so the users can access their private data.

I know that I can use asyncstorage to store something like an access token after a successful login.
But how can I validate that token on every "screen" of my app ?
How to properly check if the token exists ?

In angular I could use some interceptor to do this job.
How can I do that with react native ?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React Native + Redux basic authentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35677062/react-native-redux-basic-authentication)

Comment: Two details worth filling in: (1) Once obtained, is the token used for further remote API requests? (2) How are you managing your other app-level state? All you need to do is cache either the token itself, or a 'isLoggedIn' boolean (depending on the answer to 1), in your app state so it's available to all components (typically as a prop).

Answer (score -2):

In this you can use AsyncStorage for react native that can provide the value at every page , Go through the below link

[enter link description here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/asyncstorage.html)

Comment: Yes. But how can I check for this value ? just a simple function at avery componentWillMount ?

Comment: yes using a simple function make it work in componentWillMount

Comment: Unless your app is minuscule you don't want to check AsyncStorage in every component. Find an appropriate component (eg. the app entry point) to check, and push the answer up to state somewhere high in the app navigation tree. Then pass it down through props either manually or whatever other way you handle app state